# Continuity of probability measures for a process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_t$ be a Brownian motion, then I am given a stopping time $\tau_s:=\min(\inf\{t \ge 0; B_t=a\}, \inf\{t \ge s; B_t=b\}; \inf \{t \ge 0;B_t=c\}),$
where $a<0<b<c.$

Now, I want to show that $P(B_{\tau_s}=c)$ is a continuous function in $s.$

If anything is unclear, please let me know, I am happy to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, let $L^b_t$ be the local time of Brownian motion in state $b$, normalized so that $E[L^b_u]=\int_0^u p_t(0,b)\,dt$. Then, because $L^b_t$ is constant on the interval $[s,T_b(s)]$, 
$$
\int_s^\infty e^{-\alpha t} p_t(0,b)\,dt =E[\int_s^\infty e^{-\alpha t}\,d_tL^b_t]=E[\int_{T_b(s)}^\infty e^{-\alpha t} d_tL^b_t].
$$
Now  by the strong Markov property applied at time $T_b(s)$, the latter expectation is equal to 
$$
\eqalign{
E[e^{-\alpha T_b(s)}\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha u} d_uL^b_{T_b(s)+u}]
&=E\left[[\exp(-\alpha T_b(s))]\cdot E^b[\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha u}d_uL^b_u]\right],\cr
&=E\left[\exp(-\alpha T_b(s))\right]\cdot \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha u}p_u(b,b)\,du,\cr
}
$$
  because $L^b_\cdot$ is *additive* ($L_{u+v}=L^b_v+L^b_u\circ\theta_v$, where $\theta_v$ is the shift-time-by-$v$-units operator). (Here $E^b$ is expectation for Brownian motion started in state $b$.)

Comment: thank you, although there is something strange with the first term as you integrate over $s$ and also have $s$ as a lower limit in your integral.

Comment: That and other things now fixed.

Comment: and the expectation value is taken w.r.t. to which variable? - Apparently, you have a notation to write the first term, as an additional expectation and the previous integral w.r.t. a measure $d_tL_t^b$ that is unfamiliar to me, would you mind loosing a few words about it? Sorry, for asking all these questions, but I have never encountered this notation.

Comment: The local time at $b$, $t\mapsto L^b_t$, is continuous and non-decreasing, increasing precisely on the set of times when the Brownian motion is in state $b$.  Think of it as a random distribution function for the measure $d_tL^b_t$.

Comment: sorry, but I looked more precisely at your answer and I think there is a lot of handwaving involved in there. Especially this change of measure to $d_tL_t^b$ and the expectation value. In case you know how to make this rigorous I would certainly be interested in seeing this as it is by no means an obvious step to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It seems to me that (up to events of probability zero), the event $\{B_{\tau_s}=c\}$ is equal to the event $\{T_c<\min(T_a,s)\}$, where $T_x:=\inf\{t:B_t=x\}$.

Comment: no, it means that $\{T_c < min(T_a,T_b(s))\}$ where $T_b(s)=inf\{t \ge s: B_t=b\},$ but I don't think that this is helpful.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: but in case you see another way of doing it, I would certainly be interested in your opinion.

Comment: I'm guessing that the stochastic process $s\mapsto T_b(s)$ is stochastically continuous (in that $T_b(r)$ converges in parobability to $T_b(s)$ as $r\to s$), which would be enough for what you want.  I'll have to think about this.

Comment: Indeed, $s\mapsto T_b(s)$ is monotone non-decreasing, and $s\mapsto E[\exp(-\alpha T_s(b))]=\int_s^\infty e^{-\alpha t}p_t(0,b)\,dt/\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha u}p_u(b,b)\,du$ is continuous in $s$. (Here $p_t(x,y)$ is the Brownian transition density.) This implies that $s\mapsto T_b(s)$ is stochastically continuous, and in turn that $P[T_c<\min(T_a,T_b(s))]$ is continuous in $s$.

Comment: would you mind giving me a hint how you derived at that density for $T_b(s)$ that you used in the expectation value?

Comment: i.e. I am not saying that there is anything wrong about it, I just don't see where it follows from.

Comment: would you mind telling me whether you want to respond to this, because otherwise I will just ask another question about this distribution.

Comment: I've added some details in a follow-up answer.